# How to fix macOS Monterey showing different icons in finder and "get info"

Tags: macos, icons, macos-monterey

The icon for *.R files is shown in finder as a white file with a grey ".r". However once I open info for this file it shows the icon given by the default application to open this filetype (Rstudio): a white file with blue circle and letter "R". How do I get macOS to show this correct icon also in finder?

(macOS Monterey version 12.1)

[icon shown in finder and on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J92BE.png)

[icon shown in "get info"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vMPi.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The finder setting "View -> Show View options -> Show icon preview" needs to be deactivated in order to show the actual icon and not the "preview" of the .R source file.

Unfortunately, this means all other files like e.g. images are also shown as icon and not as preview of the content.